# Vector returning a memory exception error

Tags: c++, class, vector, sdl-2, sigabrt

I'm trying render multiple `SDL_Rect`s, each having its own `SDL_Texture` and single-lined text, to form a multi-lined text box. When its runs `CTextInput` works normally, and then when I press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> the text renders onto the first line and then suddenly crashes, reporting a memory leak.

I'm using classes to work this out. Each `CTextBox` object has its own line of text, being rendered into a `SDL_Surface` and then rendering into a `SDL_Texture`, and `SDL_Texture`, being `mTexture`. The class `CTextMenu` is made to be the administrative class. All the `CTextBox` objects get stored in the `boxes` [vector](/questions/tagged/vector), this is `std::vector<CTextBox> boxes`, which is owned by `CMenu` (the main class object of `CTextMenu)`. When `CMenu.update()` is called, all the elements in `boxes` gets rendered in a `for` loop to `SDL_Rect rcTextOutput`.

Here is the aforementioned `for` loop and `CTextMenu` class:

```
class CTextMenu
{
  std::vector<CTextBox> boxes;
  std::vector<CTextBox>::iterator it;
public:
  void update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output);
  void newBox(std::string text);
};

void CTextMenu::update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output)
{
  SDL_RenderSetClipRect(renderer, &output);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boxes.(); i++)
  {
    boxes[i].render(renderer, font, boxes[i].text, color);
    SDL_Rect dstrect;
    dstrect.x = 0;
    dstrect.y = 600 + i * boxes[i].getHeight();
    dstrect.w = boxes[i].getWidth();
    dstrect.h = boxes[i].getHeight();
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, boxes[i].getTexture(), NULL, &dstrect);
  }
}

void CTextMenu::newBox(std::string text)
{
  CTextBox box;
  box.text = text;
  boxes.insert(it, box);
  if (boxes.size() > 14)
  {
    boxes.pop_back();
  }
}
```

It seems to me there's something wrong about how I'm handling `mTexture`. I'll post the entire scripts, header and source, below.

I also ran [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) and typed `text`<kbd>RETURN</kbd>. It returned:

```
==3485== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3485== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3485== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3485== Command: build/./caventure
==3485== 
==3485== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3485==    at 0x5CF218D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
==3485==    by 0x8088BAC: ??? (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==3485==    by 0x8088FAC: ??? (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==3485==    by 0x808902C: xcb_writev (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==3485==    by 0x7D7EF3D: _XSend (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3485==    by 0x7D7F431: _XReply (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3485==    by 0x7D6A2EE: XInternAtom (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3485==    by 0x4EFB79A: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4EFC694: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4EEB87F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4EEB60E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4E4F1C6: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==  Address 0x79c5573 is 35 bytes inside a block of size 16,384 alloc'd
==3485==    at 0x4C2CF35: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3485==    by 0x7D6F385: XOpenDisplay (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3485==    by 0x4EFA84F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4EEB5BB: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x4E4F1C6: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.1)
==3485==    by 0x402002: init() (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x402333: main (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485== 
==3485== Invalid write of size 4
==3485==    at 0x402BEC: CTextBox::CTextBox(CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x403B6B: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<CTextBox>::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4030EE: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<CTextBox> >::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(std::allocator<CTextBox>&, CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4037FB: void std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::_M_insert_aux<CTextBox const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x402E16: std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox const*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x401F9F: CTextMenu::newBox(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4027A6: main (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==  Address 0xfffffffff6221c30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3485== 
==3485== 
==3485== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==3485==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFF6221C30
==3485==    at 0x402BEC: CTextBox::CTextBox(CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x403B6B: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<CTextBox>::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4030EE: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<CTextBox> >::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(std::allocator<CTextBox>&, CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4037FB: void std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::_M_insert_aux<CTextBox const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x402E16: std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox const*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x401F9F: CTextMenu::newBox(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4027A6: main (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3485==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3485==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3485==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3485==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3485== 
==3485== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3485==     in use at exit: 14,025,073 bytes in 36,583 blocks
==3485==   total heap usage: 210,985 allocs, 174,402 frees, 97,089,179 bytes allocated
==3485== 
==3485== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3485==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==3485==    indirectly lost: 176 bytes in 4 blocks
==3485==      possibly lost: 4,262,172 bytes in 30,166 blocks
==3485==    still reachable: 9,762,709 bytes in 6,412 blocks
==3485==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3485== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3485== 
==3485== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3485== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3485== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Also, if there is a more efficient way of rendering such a text box in [sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2), I will be glad to hear it.

---

**gfx.h**:

```
#ifndef __GFX_H__
#define __GFX_H__

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

class CTextBox
{
public:
  CTextBox();
  ~CTextBox();
  void free();
  void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, SDL_Color color);
  int getWidth();
  int getHeight();
  SDL_Texture* getTexture();
  std::string text;
private:
  SDL_Texture* mTexture;

  int mWidth;
  int mHeight;
};

CTextBox::CTextBox()
{
  mTexture = NULL;
  mWidth = 800;
  mHeight = 20;
  text = " ";
}

void CTextBox::free()
{
  if (mTexture != NULL)
  {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
    mTexture = NULL;
  }
}

CTextBox::~CTextBox()
{
  free();
}

void CTextBox::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, SDL_Color color)
{
  free();

  SDL_Surface* TextSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
  if (TextSurface == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Unable to render surface! ERROR: "));
  }
  mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, TextSurface);
  if (mTexture == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Unable to render texture! ERROR: "));
  }
  SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurface);

  SDL_QueryTexture(mTexture, NULL, NULL, &mWidth, &mHeight);
}

int CTextBox::getWidth()
{
  return mWidth;
}

int CTextBox::getHeight()
{
  return mHeight;
}

SDL_Texture* CTextBox::getTexture()
{
  return mTexture;
}

class CTextMenu
{
  std::vector<CTextBox> boxes;
  std::vector<CTextBox>::iterator it;
public:
  void update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output);
  void newBox(std::string text);
};

void CTextMenu::update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output)
{
  SDL_RenderSetClipRect(renderer, &output);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boxes.(); i++)
  {
    boxes[i].render(renderer, font, boxes[i].text, color);
    SDL_Rect dstrect;
    dstrect.x = 0;
    dstrect.y = 600 + i * boxes[i].getHeight();
    dstrect.w = boxes[i].getWidth();
    dstrect.h = boxes[i].getHeight();
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, boxes[i].getTexture(), NULL, &dstrect);
  }
}

void CTextMenu::newBox(std::string text)
{
  CTextBox box;
  box.text = text;
  boxes.insert(it, box);
  if (boxes.size() > 14)
  {
    boxes.pop_back();
  }
}

#endif
```

**gfx.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#include "gfx.h"

// Screen dimensions, constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900; // 600 for ground, 280 for output, 20 for input

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL; // The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL; // The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurface = NULL; // Current displayed image
TTF_Font* gFont = NULL; // Font pointer.
SDL_Color gTextColor = { 255, 255, 255, 0xFF }; // Text color, white.

CTextMenu CMenu;
CTextBox CTextInput;

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL; // The renderer we'll be using
SDL_Rect rcGround, rcSprite, rcTextInput, rcTextOutput, rcTextOutputGrd;

void init();
void loadMedia();
void quit();

void init()
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("SDL failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
  }
  else
  {
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Caventure",
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
      throw(::std::runtime_error("Window failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
    }
    else
    {
      gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
    }
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow,
                                    -1,
                                    0);
    if (gRenderer == NULL)
    {
      throw(::std::runtime_error("Renderer could not be initialised! ERROR: "));
    }
    if (TTF_Init() > 0)
    {
      throw(::std::runtime_error("TTF could not be initialised! ERROR: "));
    }
  }
}

void loadMedia()
{
  // Ground rendering
  rcGround.x = 0;
  rcGround.y = 0;
  rcGround.w = 800;
  rcGround.h = 600;

  // Sprite rendering
  rcSprite.x = 400;
  rcSprite.y = 300;
  rcSprite.w = 4;
  rcSprite.h = 4;

  // TextOutput box rendering
  rcTextOutput.x = 0;
  rcTextOutput.y = 600;
  rcTextOutput.w = 800;
  rcTextOutput.h = 280;

  // TextOutput box rendering
  rcTextOutputGrd.x = 0;
  rcTextOutputGrd.y = 600;
  rcTextOutputGrd.w = 800;
  rcTextOutputGrd.h = 280;

  gFont = TTF_OpenFont("src/graphics/resources/notomono-regular.ttf", 14);
  if (gFont == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Font load error"));
  }

  SDL_SetTextInputRect(&rcTextInput);
}

void quit()
{
  // Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
  TTF_CloseFont(gFont);
    gWindow = NULL;
  gRenderer = NULL;
  gFont = NULL;

    // Quit SDL subsystems
  TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    init();
    loadMedia();

    bool quit = false;
    bool renderText = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    std::string inputText = " ";
    std::string inputCmd = "";
    SDL_StartTextInput();

    while(!quit)
    {
      while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
      {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
          quit = true;
        }
        else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
          switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
          {
            case SDLK_UP:
            rcSprite.y -= 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            rcSprite.y += 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            rcSprite.x -= 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            rcSprite.x += 5;
            break;
          }
          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE && inputText.length() > 0)
          {
            inputText.pop_back();
            if (inputText.length() == 0)
            {
              inputText = " ";
            }
          }
          else if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN && inputText.length() != 0)
          {
            inputCmd = inputText.c_str();
            renderText = true;
            inputText = " ";
          }
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
        {
          inputText += event.text.text;
        }
      }
      if (rcSprite.x < 0 || rcSprite.y < 0 || rcSprite.y > rcGround.h || rcSprite.x > rcGround.w)
      {
        rcSprite.x = 400;
        rcSprite.y = 300;
      }

      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
      SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcGround);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcGround);

      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40);
      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcTextOutputGrd);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcTextOutputGrd);

      // Text input
      CTextInput.render(gRenderer, gFont, inputText.c_str(), gTextColor);
      rcTextInput.x = 0;
      rcTextInput.y = 880;
      rcTextInput.w = CTextInput.getWidth();
      rcTextInput.h = CTextInput.getHeight();
      SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, CTextInput.getTexture(), NULL, &rcTextInput);

      if (renderText)
      {
        // Text output
        CMenu.newBox(inputCmd.c_str());
        CMenu.update(gRenderer, gFont, gTextColor, rcTextOutput);
      }
      SDL_RenderSetClipRect(gRenderer, NULL);
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

      SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, 0, 600, 800, 600);
      SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, 0, 880, 800, 880);

      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcSprite);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcSprite);

      SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }
    SDL_StopTextInput();
  }
  catch (std::runtime_error const& msg)
    {
        printf("%s", msg.what());
        if (SDL_GetError() != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", SDL_GetError());
        }
    else if (TTF_GetError() != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", TTF_GetError());
        }
    else
    {
      printf("%s", "NULL");
    }
    quit();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valgrind error

```
==3485== Invalid write of size 4
==3485==    at 0x402BEC: CTextBox::CTextBox(CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x403B6B: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<CTextBox>::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4030EE: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<CTextBox> >::construct<CTextBox, CTextBox const&>(std::allocator<CTextBox>&, CTextBox*, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4037FB: void std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::_M_insert_aux<CTextBox const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x402E16: std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CTextBox const*, std::vector<CTextBox, std::allocator<CTextBox> > >, CTextBox const&) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x401F9F: CTextMenu::newBox(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==    by 0x4027A6: main (in /home/pradana/Projects/sierra/caventure/build/caventure)
==3485==  Address 0xfffffffff6221c30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

tells you everything you need to know: You are calling `std::vector<>::insert()` with an uninitialized iterator... Use a properly initialized, still valid iterator, and the problem should be gone.

Comment: I added `it = boxes.begin()` in the class constructor like you said, but it has the same error. Could you give me an example of a "correct constructor"?

Comment: Never mind. I removed the `std::vector<>::iterator` altogether and just used `boxes.insert(boxes.begin(), box)`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about the constructor, that hint was misleading. While you should always ensure that all your class's members are properly initialized by a constructor, iterators should generally never be part of an object in the first place: Iterators become dangling when the container they iterate reallocates its memory. As such, it is dangerous to keep an iterator around for any extended period of time. Using an iterator within `CTextMenu::newBox()` is ok, persisting it in `CTextMenu` is very likely not. I should have thought about this before typing my answer...